# using a TempDB table as my form data source, but the data doesn't display in the form

Tags: x++, dynamics-365-operations

I am using a TempDB table as a form data source and am facing an issue where the data is not showing up in the form.
Issue:
I found out by debugging, linkPhysicalTableInstance in the clicked method, it did not work well.

`TestEnumInfoTempDs.linkPhysicalTableInstance(tempTable);`

The records are getting inserted into the tempTable, but there are no records in the TestEnumInfoTempDs table and get error that

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestSearchTableEnumFormCopy.TestEnumInfoTempDs'.

I referred to this documentation: http://alexvoy.blogspot.com/2018/03/tempdb-table-on-form-with-multiple.html and implemented it in the following steps:

1. I created a Temp table with three fields.　Table Type is TempDB.
2. Created a form and set the above Temp Table at the form datasource.
3. Added populate method(the parameter is the EDT entered in the FormStringControl) to insert data into Temp Table.
4. Then override form’s init() method and initialize another tempDB buffer of the same type and link its physical instance to the current data source buffer.
5. We added the rePopulate() method to the Form and called the Populate method of the Temp Table created in #3.
6. Finally, added the clicked() method of the OK command button.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show more of your code and what you have tried so far? Also, links to tutorials or documentation you have tried are helpful. Please [edit] the question to add this information.

Comment: Thanks, I added the information to the question, you can delete the comments now. The questions mentions an error message, but not when exactly this error occurs. Could you [edit] the question (instead of answering with a comment) to add this information? You might also find it helpful to take the [tour] and look at [ask] to improve the chances of getting an answer for this question.

Comment: The question was originally tagged [dynamics-365], I retagged it to [dynamics-365-operations] since it is about this part of the Microsoft Dynamics family of products. The documentation you linked to is for an older version, [dynamics-ax-2012]. Could you clarify for which version of the product this question is about?